# How to drop string from a List that contain string values and dataframes?

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have a list that contain dataframes and string values. I want to drop only string values. When I put list.remove('Volume of imports (% change)') I got :**The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().** I want a code in loop form for many cases. How to generalize it? Thank you in advance

> ```
>    [    Country ISO3          Country Name  Indicator Id  \
>      0            ABW                 Aruba           346   
>      1            AFG           Afghanistan           346   
>      2            AGO                Angola           346   
>      3            ALB               Albania           346   
>      4            ARE  United Arab Emirates           346   
>      ..           ...                   ...           ...   
>      167          VNM               Vietnam           346   
>      168          YEM           Yemen, Rep.           346   
>      169          ZAF          South Africa           346   
>      170          ZMB                Zambia           346   
>      171          ZWE              Zimbabwe           346   
>
>                                   Indicator Subindicator Type    1980    1981  \
>      0    Gross national savings (% of GDP)          % of GDP     NaN     NaN   
>      1    Gross national savings (% of GDP)          % of GDP     NaN     NaN   
>      2    Gross national savings (% of GDP)          % of GDP  17.704  15.105   
>      3    Gross national savings (% of GDP)          % of GDP  27.121  39.852   
>      4    Gross national savings (% of GDP)          % of GDP  45.757  43.159   
>      ..                                 ...               ...     ...     ...   
>      167  Gross national savings (% of GDP)          % of GDP  12.270   8.971   
>      168  Gross national savings (% of GDP)          % of GDP     NaN     NaN   
>      169  Gross national savings (% of GDP)          % of GDP  35.318  28.097   
>      170  Gross national savings (% of GDP)          % of GDP  10.834   0.052   
>      171  Gross national savings (% of GDP)          % of GDP     NaN     NaN   
>
>             1982    1983    1984  ...    2015    2016    2017    2018    2019  \
>      0       NaN     NaN     NaN  ...  15.466  17.221  17.044  18.203  19.872   
>      1       NaN     NaN     NaN  ...  21.342  25.728  22.462  21.856  17.526   
>      2    12.419  11.463  14.437  ...  28.491  24.487  23.351  21.906  15.947   
>      3    41.023  44.479  46.845  ...  15.761  16.966  17.430  17.906  17.880   
>      4    37.663  36.592  40.707  ...  30.666  30.850  28.508  29.248  29.572   
>      ..      ...     ...     ...  ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...   
>      167  10.955  11.829  12.266  ...  27.519  29.520  29.578  29.596  29.099   
>      168     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...  -4.412  -1.366   1.956   5.084   6.783   
>      169  22.165  26.711  23.121  ...  16.323  16.381  16.432  14.582  14.430   
>      170  -0.655   6.240   7.016  ...  38.880  33.655  37.122  37.077  36.717   
>      171     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...   6.416  14.803  14.976   7.603   5.251   
>
>             2020    2021    2022    2023    2024  
>      0    19.228  18.487  17.654  16.826  15.808  
>      1    17.440  17.754  20.424  20.528  20.543  
>      2    18.147  18.359  19.004  19.650  20.219  
>      3    18.103  17.731  17.247  16.727  16.257  
>      4    28.179  27.200  26.531  26.046  25.829  
>      ..      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...  
>      167  28.605  28.339  27.952  27.305  26.739  
>      168   4.459   3.369   2.529   2.601   2.312  
>      169  14.086  14.053  14.210  14.363  14.528  
>      170  35.783  35.220  35.128  34.145  33.748  
>      171   4.945   4.713   4.679   4.607     NaN  
>
>      [172 rows x 50 columns],
>          Country ISO3          Country Name  Indicator Id  \
>      0            ABW                 Aruba           347   
>      1            AFG           Afghanistan           347   
>      2            AGO                Angola           347   
>      3            ALB               Albania           347   
>      4            ARE  United Arab Emirates           347   
>      ..           ...                   ...           ...   
>      187          WSM                 Samoa           347   
>      188          YEM           Yemen, Rep.           347   
>      189          ZAF          South Africa           347   
>      190          ZMB                Zambia           347   
>      191          ZWE              Zimbabwe           347   
>
>                                    Indicator Subindicator Type     1980     1981  \
>      0    Inflation, average consumer prices             Index      NaN      NaN   
>      1    Inflation, average consumer prices             Index      NaN      NaN   
>      2    Inflation, average consumer prices             Index      NaN      NaN   
>      3    Inflation, average consumer prices             Index      NaN      NaN   
>      4    Inflation, average consumer prices             Index   66.700   72.000   
>      ..                                  ...               ...      ...      ...   
>      187  Inflation, average consumer prices             Index   13.930   16.787   
>      188  Inflation, average consumer prices             Index      NaN      NaN   
>      189  Inflation, average consumer prices             Index    4.308    4.967   
>      190  Inflation, average consumer prices             Index    0.005    0.006   
>      191  Inflation, average consumer prices             Index  160.147  169.046   
>
>              1982     1983     1984  ...     2015     2016     2017     2018  \
>      0        NaN      NaN      NaN  ...  118.354  117.303  116.728  120.796   
>      1        NaN      NaN      NaN  ...  101.296  105.736  110.998  111.693   
>      2        NaN      NaN      NaN  ...  148.377  193.920  251.795  301.218   
>      3        NaN      NaN      NaN  ...  100.000  101.282  103.295  105.390   
>      4     77.100   78.100   80.000  ...  265.654  269.951  275.261  283.739   
>      ..       ...      ...      ...  ...      ...      ...      ...      ...   
>      187   19.859   23.128   25.871  ...  109.117  109.259  110.677  114.741   
>      188      NaN      NaN      NaN  ...  498.322  435.717  543.184  770.088   
>      189    5.683    6.392    7.117  ...   92.000   97.833  102.992  107.750   
>      190    0.007    0.008    0.010  ...  155.818  183.660  195.740  209.525   
>      191  170.043  155.671  152.780  ...   59.638   58.709   59.242   65.526   
>
>              2019     2020      2021      2022      2023      2024  
>      0    122.460  124.789   127.376   130.091   132.896   135.769  
>      1    113.815  117.799   123.099   129.254   135.717   142.503  
>      2    353.821  393.158   424.214   451.585   478.680   507.400  
>      3    107.498  110.077   113.160   116.554   120.051   123.653  
>      4    289.798  295.757   301.947   308.331   314.762   321.766  
>      ..       ...      ...       ...       ...       ...       ...  
>      187  120.639  125.766   130.168   133.813   137.560   141.411  
>      188  924.105  993.413  1043.080  1095.240  1150.000  1207.500  
>      189  113.090  119.198   125.754   132.670   139.967   147.666  
>      190  232.049  259.895   286.534   315.188   346.707   381.377  
>      191  113.638  124.281   128.880   132.746   136.728   140.830  
>
>      ,'Volume of imports (% change)',
>      'Volume of exports (% change)',
>      'General government structural balance(% of GDP)',
>      'General government net debt(% of GDP)']
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after. It filters the list for DataFrames.

```
input_list = [
    pandas.DataFrame(),
    pandas.DataFrame(),
    "test_string",
    "another_string"]

new_list = [list_entry for list_entry in input_list if type(list_entry) == pandas.DataFrame]
```